# Issue sending emails with emailjs over microsoft Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to send emails from NODEJS using emailjs. I'm connecting to a Microsoft Exchange Server, this is my configuration to connect:

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
    user:    "myUser",
    password:"1234567",
    host:    "10.220.45.17",
    tls: {ciphers: "SSLv3"}
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
buffer.js:188
        throw new TypeError('First argument needs to be a number, ' +
              ^
TypeError: First argument needs to be a number, array or string.
```

If I change the host to

```
host:    "smtp.myUser@domail.com",
```

I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: connection encountered an error]
  code: 5,
  previous: { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' },
  smtp: undefined }
```

What can be wrong this this configuration? 
Thanks!

Comment: a hostname is just `foo.bar.com`. you're trying to providing an email address, which is totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply, I changed the host name to   host:    "smtp.domain.com",  and I'm getting this error  :{ [Error: connection encountered an error]
  code: 5,
  previous: { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' },
  smtp: undefined }

Comment: then smtp.domain.com doesn't exist. maybe it's mail.domain.com or something else. you'll have to check with your mail provider